# How to set a long title for dialog dialogfragment?

Tags: android

I want the title dialog with the name of book. The problem is with the long title, it seems the default title dialog tries to trim the extra long text in order to fit the dialog width

[image]

So I came up with the solution that removing the default title by this code

```
setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
```

Replace the default with a textview widget. This is my custom dialog xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However it just mess up the dialog layout

[image]

So could anyone me a better way to deal with that ? Thanks

Comment: Think you need to create your own custom dialog. Look into themes/styles.

Comment: Could you give me more informations about that ? Thanks

Comment: search the developer site about dialogs on how to create a custom dialog

Answer (score 1):

You can use [google](https://www.google.com.pk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sa=X&ei=6yLzT_v5F-3N4QTHtMnWCQ&ved=0CEAQvwUoAQ&q=android%20custom%20dialog&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=673242acfd9407a3&biw=1241&bih=567&ion=1) to set custom view to a dialog

but don't forget to `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` :)

Answer (score 1):

So in your DialogFragments onCreate you setStyle:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.Theme_Dialog);
}
```

You then use your own very custom xml layout to create the dialog in oncreateview().